# c++ boost signals 2

Tags: c++, events, boost-signals2

In c# we have the event keyword which  is an special kind of delegate which can only be invoked from withing the class that declared it. So, is there a way of doing this in native c++ using boost::signals2, if so, is it expensive from a performance stand point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, approaches to restricting the callability a C++ function rely on passing dummy parameter of a type that either can't be instantiated outside that class (private factory or constructor with a 'friend' declaration for the intended class).

Applying this to a boost::signals2::signal would result in a signal definition that had the extraneous parameter, though.

If you really need to make it un-callable, remember that it is just an object member (at least, as I use it...) - you can declare it as a private or protected member and provide a public function for connecting to it.

```
class FooEmitter
{
public:
    boost::signals2::scoped_connection ConnectToFoo(boost::function<void (Emitter&)>& handler)
    {
        return fooSignal.connect(handler);
    }

    void triggerFoo() {
        fooSignal(*this);
    }
private:
    boost::signals2::signal<void (Emitter&)> fooSignal;
};

class FooHandler
{
public:
    FooHandler()
    {
        fooConnection = getAnEmitter().ConnectToFoo(boost::bind(&FooHandler::HandleFoo, this, _1);
    }

    void HandleFoo(Emitter&)
    {
        // handler body
    }

private:
    boost::signals2::scoped_connection fooConnection;
}
```

You could of course re-arrange the ConnectToFoo method to take a FooHandler& and do the binding in there, if your model is rigid enough.

As for the performance aspect, the dummy type is effectively free with a good compiler, and this mechanism is an additional function call or two once per handler (not per signal).